# Redirect doesn't work for codeplex from 000webhost.com

Tags: php, html, redirect

I am making a website to public my project that is on adhoc.codeplex.com but when i am linking download button to the codeplex, instead of redirecting to codeplex it stop loading and display nothing. I'd tried both method:

1) Linking download button to codeplex via:

```
<a href="https://adhoc.codeplex.com">Download</a>
```

2) Redirecting through php via :

```
<?php
    header( 'Location:https://adhoc.codeplex.com' );
?>
```

My working website is on www.adhoc.co.nr.
What can I do please suggest something ?

Comment: I take it the link works, but the redirect doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

You're most likely getting an error that stops execution of the `header()` - probably "headers already sent."

Two ways to go about it;

- Don't output anything before the `header()`
- Use a `meta` refresh

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='https://adhoc.codeplex.com'" />
```

Comment: OP, in relation to the first suggestion, turn on `error_reporting` and `display_errors` to see if a warning is emitted. On live sites, only do this temporarily.

Comment: I have tried it but its not working, .co.nr is a free domain provider service , I have tried on original site and the redirection work but when i try from adhoc.co.nr it doesn't work.

Comment: A free domain doesn't matter, it still points to your server, right? Do any errors come up? When you say "doesn't work", do you mean it doesn't redirect (& how are you redirecting)? Have you looked in the error log?

Answer (score 0):

**is header already sent error in 000webhost?**
*you must update your .htaccess file with following lines of code...*
php_value display_errors 1
php_flag output_buffering on

Answer (score 0):

use `echo "<script>window.location.replace('https://adhoc.codeplex.com');</script>";` instead of `header( 'Location:https://adhoc.codeplex.com' );`. it will definitely work.